# Are sharepoint forms built from infopath secure?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I was wondering; does Infopath/Sharepoint ever use any filtering or sanitization of a form, in order to prevent malicious injection code? I recently went from building my forms from scratch in PHP to using Infopath/Sharepoint and wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, InfoPath is saving the data in XML format, so i guess it's theoretically possible, however i've never heard about it before. In the form itself, you can enable "Validation" on each field i.e. only numbers, only certain condition or even apply RegEx.